How to measure where culprit is, in a Commodore 128D (plastic model) PSU?
I do have a problem with my C128D PSU, and with some help from others I think I may have identified that it must be on the primary side (230V) of things. It seems not to provide any voltage for the TR1 and TR2 transformers, so naturally no output will be given on the secondary side, and the main problem here is, that I do not get any 5VDC between the red and black wires on the secondary side (this is sw can rt in below schematics).
Translation from the German schematic:

sw = black wires (DC ground)
rt = red wires (5VDC)
ge = yellow wire (is this 12VDC ?)
or = orange wires (this is AC)

As I have no electrical skills, then I am very careful when measuring anything on the PSU board, but I am not affraid of it, so I kindly would like to ask if any of you guys can help me identifying what the problem could be here?
The information I have so far is as follows, and though this schematics is very simple compared to other stuff, well then it is not that logical/easy for me to understand.
The full schematics are available here, https://www.zimmers.net/anonftp/pub/cbm/schematics/computers/c128/power/ps-128d-german.gif but I have put a copy here:

I have narrowed the issue down to this area here, where I also have done some measurements already. The problem as I see it is that (measured both AC and DC):

TR1 pin 13+16 is 0V
TR1 pin 12+15 is 0V
TR2 pin 1+2 is 0V


As far as I can understand, then the voltage after the bridge rectifier (GR1) seems OK?
Also, the TR3 and 9VAC seems to be fine, after I fixed a broken trace on the primary side. I have measured all traces on primary side, and cannot find any more broken traces.
I have of course also inspected for blown capacitors or transistors, but I cannot see any that looks weird.
For the "Diode Test" (DT) I have measured with power off.
For the voltage measurements I have measured with power on, but with no load (not connected to motherboard).
I do believe that I have measured correctly, but I sadly see myself as a noob for measurements, so please let me know if I should double-check something or redo it in another way. I have measured between the two legs of the component, within the circuit as-is (I did not desolder anything yet).
I have already looked into other posts also - like these two:

A problem with an old computer PSU (schaffer-bv-223-5-04008)
What are these electronic components found inside a Schaffer BV 223-5-04008 PSU for the Commodore 128D?

And just again to copy some relevant information then I have these two from the other posts:


Sadly there seems to exists NO component partslist at all for this power supply :-(
I do not have spareparts already, as I then would have tried swapping, and ideally I would like to know and be sure if I am even on the right track here, or if the fault is somewhere completely different?

UPDATE #1
@Burglups commented that I should replace C6, C8, D1 and D2, but I have no idea what kind of diodes these are, and the green one is also unknown to me. I can of course identify C6, which is a 10uF/50V capacitor, but what are the other three?
What is the green one, C6, here?

This shows D1, but exactly what diode is this?

And here is the D2 one - looks like the same to me but ... ?

@D.A.S. commented that I should "verify the continuity of the primary windings of TR1 especially (16-13)", but how exactly to do that? Would that be putting it into Diode Test mode, and then measure between T1 pin 13+16 or .. ?
Do note that on the primary side, I have already checked for broken traces on all solder joints, and I cannot measure any.

It looks like the primary-side oscillator, that's supposed to drive TR1 as some type of switching converter, isn't oscillating the way it's supposed to. What measurement equipment do you have? An oscilloscope would be greatly helpful here.

I do have an oscilloscope (Rigol DS2202A), but I am a little reluctant using it with 230V, as I am also a novice for oscilloscope  I have a feeling, that I could end up damaging the scope, and then I would rather just use my multimeter.

With power off , pls verify the continuity of the primary windings of TR1 especially (16-13).   The DT uses low current (e.g. 1mA) and ought to read near 0V.    If Ok you could verify the traces of nodes for broken solder joints on TR1. (hairline circle crack around pin from being dropped or vibration fatigue.)

The diodes should have their part numbers printed on them. It likely won't be possible to read them without removing the diodes first. The number will probably start with 1N, and then there will be three  to four numbers following, e.g. 1N4148 is a common diode.

From what I can see in the pictures, D1 and D2 do have 1N visible. As Hearth says will probably have to remove them to read the full identity.

Do you have an isolated 230 VAC supply? This would allow to inject starting pulses from a signal generator like C8 does once at power on.

@Jens - I do not have a dedicated/isolated power supply.

I created an abstract subset of your circuit, that can show you the signal waveforms you can expect in the circuit when operating properly.
Since most component values are unknown, I used some generic plausible values here. This is the reason why the flyback pulse looks a bit ugly, but this is not so important in a diagnostic session.
The startup generator, here V2, is some 555 like 12 V square wave circuit. Cut the connection between C8 and (R14, R15) and inject the square wave there.
If you have two old 12V transformers for halogen bulbs, you can connect them back to back. The first one steps down from mains to 12 V and the second steps up again from 12 V to mains level and provides isolation. Then there is no danger if you connect scope GND to this circuit (e.g. main rectifier minus).
As an alternative, the whole circuit can be operated from an isolated bench top DC supply, 40-60V might be just enough across C5. But again you probably need the square wave generator to force triggering of T1.
Play with the simulator, good luck!

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

This is very nice of you, but I sadly think I understand this one as little as the real stuff. I have got it to work, so it at least shows 312V over C8, but on the right side of that it always show 74nV (0V), which I don't understand.
